# Is there a Keygen Example?

Tags: html

I can't seem to find any implementation of an actual usage of the keygen element. The best demonstration that I have found, simply echos back the public key.

Is there a demonstration of usage? I.e. an actual authentication?

Comment: The way the internet works, you don't need a keygen. Instead, you will need an API key, or an Authorization access key or something similar. Keygen are known to be only for desktops. I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but do you have anything in mind?

Comment: @FranzNoel Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_keygen.asp).

Comment: Yes. Are you trying to create an application, and you want to use the username and security as the password?

Comment: @FranzNoel That would be an improvement over the aforementioned echo.

Comment: Well keygen is totally useless in my opinion.
Because it is browser dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a full TLS authentication example using PHP and Apache [there](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/attachments/20080714/07ea5534/attachment.txt).

However, according to [BrowserAuth.net](http://www.browserauth.net/tls-client-authentication), this kind of authentication suffers from multiple problems.

The most annoying is, in my opinion, the credential portability problem. Namely, private keys cannot be extracted from the underlying platform and can't be moved from one device to another.

There will probably be no standard API to extract the private key (because this will be a bad security practice), so you can't use the `<keygen>` element as a private/public key generator.

See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27955/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawbacks-of-the-html5-keygen-element